# How to send information on my email from django form? - Django 2

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap, forms

How to send information on my email from django form. Now I can see information only in my console [output on my cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtU0R.png)

template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% block title %}
    Contact Us
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h2 class="mt-4 ml-4">Contact Me</h2>
<form method="post">
<div class="container mt-4">
    {% csrf_token %}
   <div class="col-md-4">
        {{ form.subject.label }}
        {% render_field form.subject class+="form-control" %}
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
        {{ form.email.label }}
        {% render_field form.email type="email" class+="form-control" %}
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
        {{ form.message.label }}
        {% render_field form.message class+="form-control" rows="4" cols="6" %}
   </div>
   <div class="form-actions">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2 ml-3">Send</button>
   </div>
</div>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    subject = forms.CharField(required=True)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=False)
```

views.py:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import ContactForm

def emailView(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, email, ['yarik.nashivan@gmail.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('success')
    return render(request, "email.html", {'form': form})

def successView(request):
    return HttpResponse('Success! Thank you for your message. <p>You will be redirected to the main page in 3 seconds.</p> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=/"> ')
```

Don't look at it: fgkjdfldfjgndfkgndfskj vdafk kjdsjaf jjjfd jdsaf dj fdsjn dnjndfj jdffjk hdsffdfgfdb sfdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are using [console backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/email/#console-backend), that is why you are seeing the message in console. If you use [SMTP backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/email/#smtp-backend), then you can send this email to your acccount. For that, you need to configure like this:

First you need to update the backend in settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

Then update the smtp configurations in `settings.py`:

```
# this configuration is for gmail
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'test@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'test'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

For details, please check the [email documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/email) for Django.

Comment: ERROR: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials g12-v6sm14949570lja.74 - gsmtp')

Comment: On line: send_mail(subject, message, email, ['yarik.nashivan@gmail.com'])

Comment: `EMAIL_HOST_USER` and `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` should be your email address and password. I have given dummy ones with the answer.

Comment: Stop, can I do it if I'm on a localhost? Or I need hosting?

Comment: Yes, you can do that in localhost.

Comment: I fond an answer for my question. https://myaccount.google.com/security